# ipad app development: Block_copy not working

Tags: objective-c

I am new to this site, I hope you can help.

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error from the following code in function():

```
typedef int (^BlockDef)();
BlockDef getBlockDef(int d)
{
    BlockDef def = Block_copy(^()
    {
        return d;
    });

    return def;
}

void function()
{
    BlockDef def1 = getBlockDef(1);
    BlockDef def2 = getBlockDef(2);

    printf("%d\n",def1());
    printf("%d\n",def2());

    NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray array];
    [arr addObject:def1];
    [arr addObject:def2];

    printf("%d\n",((BlockDef) [arr objectAtIndex:0])()); // **** EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
    printf("%d\n",((BlockDef) [arr objectAtIndex:1])());
}
```

This code runs without any problem in iphone, but not in ipad. What may be the problem?

Also, in ipad, when I remove the Block_copy call, it runs through the same line successfully. This is weird since a non copied function sould not be returned or should not be called (In iphone, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at first printf's in this situation).

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say iPad, do you mean 3.2? If so this won't work. There is a half finished blocks API  in 3.2 that will let you do everything, except copy blocks.

If your iPad is on 4.2 and this still doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: sdk is 4.0.2, I don't have an ipad device now (but I will get it tomorrow), I ran this code in simulator. Would updating to 4.2 solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, if you are on the 4.0 SDK your iPad sim is 3.2

Comment: Probably need to get the 4.2 SDK as well as the iPad.